# Keeping text selection color the same with different backgrounds

Tags: css

I am using a custom text selection color (pink) on a website. This is fine when the text is on a white background. However, I also have blue colored boxes with text. In these boxes, the pink 'reacts' to the blue and becomes purplish. I want the text selection color to be the same as on the white background. Can this be done?

[Sample fiddle](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FHTXYSLUTW35)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've got a tricky solution:

```
::selection {
   background: rgba(242, 190, 180, 0.99);
}
```

You have to change the opacity of the color to 1, but 1 does not work properly so as 0.99 does.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works pretty well! But strange that opacity of 1 doesn't work. Any idea why?